# How to copy file content to another file in Ansible without overwriting the second file

Tags: ansible

I have a file called `a.txt` which has following contents:

```
123
456
986
231
456
```

And I have another file in the `/etc/file2.txt` and has below content:

```
test values
some values
hello world how are you
```

And I want to copy the content of file `a.txt` to `/etc/file2.txt`, so I did this:

```
- name: Copy from a.txt to file2.txt
  copy:
    src: "a.txt"
    dest: "/etc/file2.txt"
```

But this **Overrides and replaces the whole contents in the file2.txt**

But I want it to be like this:

```
test values
some values
hello world how are you
123
456
986
231
456
```

Can someone give me a help?

Comment: `But this Overrides and replaces the whole contents in the file2.txt` => this is exactly what is expected when you copy a file.

Answer (score 5):

Then you don't want to copy the file. You want to append the content of `a.txt` to `/etc/file2.txt`.

From your above example, `a.txt` is on your controller while `/etc/file2.txt` is on your target.

A first quick and dirty approach can be done directly with the shell module:

```yaml
- name: Unconditionnaly append content of a.txt to /etc/file2.txt
  shell: echo "{{ lookup('file', 'a.txt') }}" >> /etc/file2.txt
```

Now this is kind of dirty and will always append the content, even if this was already done earlier.  An other possible approach is to use the `blockinfile` module:

```yaml
- name: Make sure a.txt content is present in /etc/file2.txt
  blockinfile:
    path: /etc/file2.txt
    block: "{{ lookup('file', 'a.txt') }}"
```

This is already better as the content of the file will be added only if not already there or because it changed. Meanwhile, this method will add block markers in the file and you should make sure they are comptible with your requirements (see the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html) for more info)

My prefered method would definitely be a template. Keeping the `a.txt` file as it is, create on your controller a file `templates/file2.txt.j2`:

```
test values
some values
hello world how are you
{{ lookup('file', 'a.txt') }}
```

From there all you need is:

```yaml
- name: Make sure `/etc/file2.txt` is aligned to our template
  template:
    src: file2.txt.j2
    dest: /etc/file2.txt
```

Comment: by the way what is `src: file2.txt` ?

Comment: The template on your controller (will be looked in a `templates` forlder by default). I renamed the file in my answer with the usual `.j2` extension to make this clearer.